# Cleaning an email list with emails containing only numbers or -- or . in front of the @ symbol

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a list of email address I am cleaning. quite a few of them contain only numbers in front of the @ sign, or only numbers separated by a . character.

For example:

100050.3555@domainname.com

I am having a difficult time with:

> `sed -e '/^\d+\./d' file > temp && mv temp file`

or

> `sed -e '/^\d+/d' file > temp && mv temp file`

or

> `sed -e '/^\d+\.+/' file > temp && mv temp file`

or

> `sed -e '/^\[0-9]+\.+/d' file > temp && mv temp file`

None of these commands are removing the data.

Usually I can use

> `egrep -c [whatever character or string] file`

And, if egrep can detect it and provide a count, then I can feel comfortable executing a command. When I used:

> `egrep -c [^\/d+@] file`

This displayed 0 results. But, there are many many than that in the file.

> `egrep -c [\/d+@] file`

This seems to display all of the email addresses, even those without digits.

I also need help filtering emails like:

- 1.0.7@text.text.text.com
- 1.0.7@text.text.text.com
- 1-gemini@text.com
- 1-gemini@text.com
- 1-2-3@numbersonly.net
- 0fxu00001wtx1a@text.com
- 0f31e5c394dad311b60c00e029101a0704101166@text.text.text.com
- 0f.@numbersonly.net
- 0d07mtouk50ao0cusrn8soq7cfdb33v5fn@4ac.com
- 0_0100@text.com 099ridge@text.text.text.za

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: `sed` needs `\+` (backslashed) unless you use `sed -r`. GNU sed understands `\d` but other seds probably won't. https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html

Comment: @glennjackman GNU sed does not understand `\d`. GNU sed does understand `\w`, `\W` ,`\s`,`\S`,`\b`,`\<`,`\>` and `\B` to name a few

Answer (score 2):

This command should work:

```
sed -e '/^[0-9.]*@/d' file
```

If you want to change the file in place, add the `-i` parameter (instead of creating a temp file).

The reason your previous commands don't work comes from a syntax problem. By default, sed uses the BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax for patterns. This syntax doesn't handle the `\d` shorthand character class nor the `+` quantifier.

Comment: Thank you! I am testing it as we speak.

Comment: I need some help with other types of obviously fake email addresses like I have later edited and listed in my question. Can you help me with a command for those, too, please?

Comment: GNU sed understands `\+` and `\?` (BRE) and `+` and `?` (ERE) but the POSIX standard ???

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `egrep -v`:

```
egrep -v "^[0-9\\.]+@" spamlist.txt
```

---

[egrep man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep)

-v, --invert-match  ->> select non-matching lines

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas on the other types of email addresses I need to filter out of this dirty list?

Comment: I guess you'll have to build several customizes filters, because some of the email you's posted are, in deed, valid emails.

Comment: That is correct. If you can help  with any of these filters, please do as it is appreciated. I am just trying to lighten the load of my DNS and SMTP engine validation program and ultimately my hosting. Thank you!

Comment: For example, for email addresses like 199608202329.qaa08476@word-word.word.word.com, and specifically the part before the @, I think I should use: > 'egrep -e -i -v '^[:digit:]\.\w[:digit:]*@' file > temp && mv temp file'